# Teradata Temporary Table

Tags: sql, teradata, temp-tables

I need help with creating temporary tables in Teradata. Below I am creating a global temporary table  TOPTABLE3. Then I am inserting 10 rows into the table. However, then when I query the table, I only get 0 rows returned which shows that the records were not inserted into the temporary table. Thanks in advance.

```
CREATE global temporary table  TOPTABLE3 (
TABLE1  VARCHAR(20))
```

-- CREATE TABLE completed. 0 rows processed. Elapsed Time = 00:00:01

```
INSERT INTO TOPTABLE3 
SEL          top 10 TABLE1  
FROM    schema.table 
where       table.column1 = 'D'  
and  table.column2 = CAST('01/01/2017' AS DATE FORMAT 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

-- INSERT completed. 10 rows processed. Elapsed Time = 00:00:06 Output directed to Answer window

```
SELECT  *
FROM     My_ID.TOPTABLE3
```

-- SELECT completed. 0 rows returned. Elapsed Time = 00:00:02

Comment: My first guess is that `TOPTABLE3` <> `My_SID.TOPTABLE3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do a `SHOW TABLE` you will spot the `ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS` option, which is based on Standard SQL, but quite useless in Teradata (unless you switch to ANSI-sessions).

You run a Teradata session which defaults to one transaction per request and the *We send out an END TRANSACTION step* in Explain truncates the table.

Use `ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS` instead.

Btw, instead of `CAST('01/01/2017' AS DATE FORMAT 'MM/DD/YYYY')` you better use a date literal which is always `YYYY-MM-DD`:

```
DATE '2017-01-01'
```